# How to run F# interactive (fsi.exe) in dotnet core? Is it supported yet?

Tags: .net, linux, f#, .net-core, f#-interactive

I cannot run find/run fsi.exe either in windows or linux on dotnetcore. It is nowhere to be found. Maybe it is not supported yet?

Comment: Did you find a way to use the F# REPL with .NET Core?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please correct me if I'm wrong but, today (Dec '19)
f# interactive with netcore is working in Ubuntu 18.04
With the standard installation instructions from
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-package-manager-ubuntu-1904
and https://fsharp.org/use/linux/

```ml
// file: runtime.fsx
open System
open System.Reflection
open System.Runtime
open System.Linq

Type.GetType("Mono.Runtime")
|> printf "Mono.Runtime: %A\n"
(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetCustomAttributesData()
         .FirstOrDefault((fun a -> 
            a.AttributeType = typedefof<Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute>)))
         .ConstructorArguments
|> printf "Framework: %A\n"
```

```
$ fsi runtime.fsx 
Mono.Runtime: Mono.Runtime
Framework: seq [".NETFramework,Version=v4.6"]
```

...

```
$ dotnet fsi runtime.fsx 
Mono.Runtime: <null>
Framework: seq [".NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1"]
```

Answer (score 7):

[F# for CoreCLR Status](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/wiki/F%23-for-CoreCLR---Status) says that FSI on CoreCLR is complete, so presumably it would work if one could find it.

In another ticket — [Why were the C# and F# REPLs removed and when/how will it implemented "as a separate tool"?](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/3913) — it's claimed that `dotnet repl fsi` used to work but was removed in favour of an (as yet non-existent) separate package.